# How to use built in actions Snap Ins SDK Swift

Tags: ios, snap-ins

I'm following the documentation for Snap Ins SDK for iOS but I'm not understanding how to use built in actions.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/customize_action_buttons.htm

I've set up a proof of concept app using the examples on the docs and have made a custom button - but I don't get how to utilize a built in action (in this case, "chatInterface"). Is there a way to pass in built in actions to the list of default actions or am I missing something here. The example only shows how to add a custom button, but I am trying to leverage what I think is supposed to be built into the SDK. Some boilerplate code would be extremely helpful.

summary - I just want to launch a live agent chat from the knowledge interface (so add a button next to article search, then have it launch chat)